# Android posting to PHP

Tags: php, android, post

I'm new to Android and I want to work on taking data and sending it to a database through PHP, the issue I'm having is I'm unsure on what to do with the input. My goal is to have the user input a string on the android application and have it sent to a database through PHP. Here's my code:

```
package com.example.signals;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stream Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return total.toString();
}



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
final EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){    

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/script.php?var1=androidprogramming");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if(response != null) {
                String line = "";
                InputStream inputstream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                line = convertStreamToString(inputstream);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to complete your request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Caught ClientProtocolException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Caught IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Caught Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
}}'
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Do you have issue on the php or on the android side?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input as a string:

```
input.getText().toString();
```

And append it to your url as a GET param

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an HTTP request.  Passing data via JSON is very convenient from Android:
Simply pass in whatever data you need to send and have it wrapped in JSON like below.
The 'text' field is returned and can be parsed from JSON as needed

```
private String postPullData(JSONObject json, String URL) throws JSONException { 
    HttpClient httpclient;
    int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 20*1000;
    int WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 20*1000;
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    String Error = "SCOMM Error: ";
    JSONArray postjson;
    URL url = null;


        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, WAIT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


        try {

            postjson = new JSONArray();
            postjson.put(json);

            // Post the data:
            httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            System.out.print(json);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // for JSON:
            if (response != null)
            {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Error += " IO Exception: " + e;
                    Log.d("SCOMM", Error);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Error;
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        Error += " closing connection: " + e;
                        Log.d("SCOMM", Error);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return Error;
                    }
                }

                return sb.toString();
           <snip> 
           // more error recovery stuff below
```

Comment: I've only taken one class on Android development but I'm understanding most of this, just want to clarify a few things. Once it returns the string builder how do  connect that to the edit text field I have on the XML? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append your data to the URL using GET/POST method. See this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).

```
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First:you can't send data in main thread to server. Second: use HttpGet rather than HttpPost. Get user data you can `input.getText.toString()`. use `AsynckTask` for send data to server

```
class SendData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://example.com/script.php?var1=androidprogramming");
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        if(response != null) {
                            String line = "";
                            InputStream inputstream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                            line = convertStreamToString(inputstream);
                            return line;
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        //toas can't use here
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    if(s != null){
                        //toast here!
                    }
                }
            }
```

usage

```
new SendData().execute()
```